# If you have unlimited space, how many toilets can you put into a public restroom?

Tags: structures, architecture

Are there structural limits or legal limits of any kind?

Comment: Well, the practical limit if there are no others is how many flushes you expect to happen at the same time. The water pipes can only handle so much.

Comment: Depending on the capacity of the waste collection, conveying, and processing system, It would be a structural concern if you stack the toilet up.

Comment: If you have unlimited space than you can make main collections pipes are large at you need to and install any back flow prevention apparatus if required.  I would say the limiting factor is how long you can hold it why you make your way to the only open toilet at the far end.

Comment: You would be limited potentially by fire codes.   There will be a maximum distance to an emergency exit.

Comment: @RexxiA, you are on an international site. You have not specified a location and you haven't given one in your user profile. Your question doesn't indicate that you have done any research.

Answer (score 1):

In a search engine look up *public toilet regulations*.

Regulations for public toilets can vary by jurisdiction (country, state or province, municipal authority). Most national standards organizations have standards for public toilets. Some regulations I've seen online state the sizes for toilet cubicles, heights of toilet seats & the height a coat hook needs to be from the floor, amongst other things. Check the regulations for your region of interest.